# SSRS Tablix Groupings with NULL as Wildcard

Tags: group-by, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

My source query produces something like:

```
| timestamp                | inUser | outUser | xferUser | taskID |
| 2018-03-01 17:00:00.000  | USER.A | NULL    | NULL     | 1234   |
| 2018-03-02 14:00:00.000  | NULL   | USER.A  | NULL     | 2345   |
| 2018-03-02 15:00:00.000  | USER.B | NULL    | NULL     | 2312   |
| 2018-03-03 12:00:00.000  | NULL   | USER.A  | NULL     | 9283   |
| 2018-03-04 13:00:00.000  | NULL   | NULL    | USER.C   | 1928   |
| 2018-03-04 13:59:00.000  | NULL   | USER.A  | USER.C   | 1883   |
| 2018-03-05 14:01:00.000  | NULL   | NULL    | USER.B   | 9910   |
```

I'm trying to make a summary table to shows the [Count(inUser)], [Count(outUser)], & [Count(xferUser)] by each user:

```
| user   | inCount | outCount | xferCount |
| USER.A | 1       | 3        | 0         |
| USER.B | 1       | 0        | 1         |
| USER.C | 0       | 0        | 2         |
```

I can get this pretty close with the column groupings by inUser, outUser, & xferUser. But I run into issues with the NULL values group together.

I can also do this by have multiple matrix, one for each column, but I'd rather try and combine them as it gives a better visualization for each user over all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can edit your datasource I would suggest formatting the output as follows... (I've left out timestamp values to save me typing!)

```
taskID  State       UserID   TimeStamp
1234    'inUser'    'USER.A' 
2312    'inUser'    'USER.B.'
1883    'outUser'   'USER.A' 
1883    'xferUser'  'USER.C'
etc...
```

Then you can build a simple matrix with row grouping by `UserID` and column grouping by `State`. The data cell would simply be a count and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Alan. I was able to update my datasource and achieve the groupings that I desired.